# Spring + Angular - URL handling

Tags: angular, spring, tomcat

I have Spring Boot app with this version:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.1.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>
```

Frontend part is running on Angular 7. My Tomcat version is Apache Tomcat/8.5.34
I have couple of endpoints that are handled by Spring. What I want to achieve is to let Angular handle some of endpoints.
For example: `/endpoint1` and `/endpoint2` are handled by Spring, but `/endpoint3` and `/endpoint4` must be handled by Angular

I tried to implement this by adding this `ViewController`:

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class ViewController {

    @RequestMapping({ "/endpoint3", "/endpoint4" })
    public String index() {
        return "forward:/index.html";
        //return "forward:/";   also tried with this
    }
}
```

However, I still get 404 when I try to access those endpoints. What am I doing wrong? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You have to use the RouterModule https://angular.io/guide/router

Comment: Can you give me an example, how to implement your suggestion ?

Comment: The example is in the link above. Or as a working example: https://angular.io/generated/live-examples/router/stackblitz.html